# React Js Bundle to another website like wordpress or php site

Tags: javascript, php, reactjs, wordpress

I'm beginner and learning using React.js. I want to know if I compile react to bundle.js can it work to Wordpress or another php site?

I just need information about it for my current project. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I don't really know what your idea and why you want to do it.

The main problem is in routing.
Wordpress is CMS with own routing/permalinks system where every created post type has unique url.
If you're building SPA with React routing, you cannot use it together with Wordpress. This would work only on separate domains/subdomains (one for Wordpress and one for React.js app) and communicate across Rest API.

If your React.js app doesn't have own routing, you can use it with Wordpress. You can easily add specific HTML element to your Wordpress post type (by default it is `<div id="root"></div>` - you can find where is app binded in your index.js/.tsx file), where will be rendered your React.js app and insert link of bundle script to footer of your Wordpress site.

So, imagine that your React.js app is something like "same-origin iframe", which you can add to your website.

If my answer didn't help you, please add more information.